# how can I get Ubuntu 32-bit? It seems you can no longer get it off the Ubuntu website

Tags: 32-bit

I am trying to get Ubuntu 32 bit because the computer i am putting it on has 2 GB of RAM. I can no longer find the 32 bit download on Ubuntu's website. Can someone help me? Link or instruction how to get to the 32 bit download.

Comment: You can run the 64-bit version on [as little as 1GB RAM](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch03s04.html).

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 16.04 https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/ → → http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-mate-16.04-desktop-i386.iso

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Alternative Downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

1. Scroll to Bottom, select Other Images, and your appropriate conutry.
2. Click a Version Number
3. Choose an image ending in `-i386.iso`

I recommend against using the most current version, but I strongly encourage choosing an LTS release.

Answer (score 0):

All the ISOs for Ubuntu 16.04 can be found at http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/. If you want a 32-bit (also called i386) version, the download link is http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso.